# Which file is read and executed when interactive non-login bash session exits?

Tags: bash, files, logout

Which file is read and executed when interactive non-login bash session exits?
 For example interactive login bash executes `~/.bash_logout` if it exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None.

To have the interactive non-login shell source a file upon exiting, set a trap in `.bashrc`:

```
shopt -q login_shell || trap '. "$HOME/.bash_non-login_logout"' EXIT
```